# Wireless Drivers for D-Link DWA-182

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers

Just wondering if any drivers are out there for D-Link DWA-182 Wireless Adapter for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS ?

Comment: So I see Ubuntu 14.04.1 is out !  Still haven't been able to install the driver for D-Link DWA-182 ! There are NO inf.files to be found !  Another other suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you might need to use the ndiswrapper to make that adaptor work.  You can find information on that on the [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper) website.

Answer (score 0):

Download the installer for the device I to had the problem with D-Link but the only solution is to get the drivers rpm package form the device internal storage itself and install it manually if you get the package (rpm package) you are ready to install

and also take a look at this for more help

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2102085